# How to replace all email addresses in a set of files with a generic email address

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I have some scripts which have many email address in different domain (say `domain1.com`,`domain2.com` . I want to replace all of them with some generic email address in a common domain, say `domain.com`, keeping rest of the script same.

I am using below in `sed` but it doesn't seem to work. (it is returning same output as input, so looks like the search is not matching. However, when I tested the regex `\S+@\S+/` in online tester, it seems to match email addresses.)

> `s/\S+@\S+/genericid@domain.com/g`

For example, I have 2 scripts

```
$ cat script1.sh
abcd.efg@domain.com
export SENDFROM="xyz@domain1.com" blah_4

$ cat script2.sh
echo foo|mailx -s "blah" pqr@domain2.com,def@domain.com,some@domain.com
 omg@domain.com
foo abc@domain.com bar
```

My result after `sed -i` should be

```
$ cat script1.sh
genericid@domain.com
export SENDFROM="genericid@domain.com" blah_4

$ cat script2.sh
echo foo|mailx -s "blah" genericid@domain.com,genericid@domain.com,genericid@domain.com
 genericid@domain.com
foo genericid@domain.com bar
```

I am using `Linux 3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64`

Any suggestion please?

Update: 
I managed to make it work with `'s/\S\+@\S\+.com/genericid@domain.com/g'`. There were 2 problem with previous `search`.

- The `+` needed `\` before it.
- As file had other `@` lines (for
  database connections), I had to append `.com` at the end, as all my
  addresses ended in `.com`

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to mention. It is returning the same output as input. Edited the question with the same input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Other answers, and comments on this one, point out that you may have to take extra steps to enable shorthand character class matching; I'm used to doing regex in perl, where this just works, so didn't think to address that possibility.  This answer only addresses how to improve the matching once you have the regex functioning.

--

While the problem of matching email addresses with regex can be very complex (and in fact in the most general case isn't possible with true regex), you probably can handle your specific case.

The problem with what you have is that \S matches any non-whitespace, so `address@something.com,address@somethingelse.com`, where two addresses have no whitespace between, matches incorrectly.

So there's a couple ways to go about it, based on knowing what sorts of addresses you realistically will see.  One solution would be to replace *both* instances of `\S` with `[^\s,]` (note the lowercase s), which simply excludes `,` from the match as well as whitespace.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but when I used `s/\S+@[^\S,]+/genericid@domain.com/g`, I am getting same output as input.

Comment: In a basic regular expression `\S` stands for `\ ` and `S` literally.  That's why you're having difficulty with it.

Comment: @Usav - in addition to Toby's advice (which I was unaware of; apparently I've been using perl for too long), also the expression in your comment isn't a correct application of what I recommended for two reasons.  (1) in the new expression the `\s` must be lowercase, not capital; (2) you need to replace **both** `\S` instances

Comment: I managed to make it work with `'s/\S\+@\S\+.com/genericid@domain.com/g'` . Problem was the `+` sign, which needed to be bachshashed. After that I ran into another trouble, but managed that by hardcoding `.com` at the end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Capturing email adresses using regex can be more difficult than it seems.
Anyhow, for replacing the domain, I think you could simplistically consider that an email domain starts when it find:

`1 alphanum char` + `@` + `N alphanum chars` + `.` + `N alphanum chars`

Based on this preconception, in javascript I would do so:

> (\w@)(\w*.\w*)

Replacing with:

> $1newdomain.com

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to make it work with `'s/\S\+@\S\+.com/genericid@domain.com/g'` as I have all the address ending in `.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed s/[^,@]*@[^,]*/genericid@domain.com/g
```

and

```
echo 'pqr@domain2.com,def@domain.com,some@domain.com' | sed s/[^,@]*@[^,]*/genericid@domain.com/g
```

result

```
genericid@domain.com,genericid@domain.com,genericid@domain.com
```

Comment: Try adding some explanations ;-)

Comment: It is removing remaining part of lines, where email address is there. So `export SENDFROM="xyz@domain1.com" blah_4` is replaced by just `genericid@domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Still UNIX-related, though requiring the more modern and far from ubiquitous tool, [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/), you could use [email-replace](https://github.com/bbarker/email-replace/blob/master/src/email-replace.sc).

```
$ amm path/to/email-replace.sc <random integer seed> <file1 with emails> <file2 with emails> ...
```

**DISCLAIMER:** the matcher is likely far from perfect, so use at your own risk, and always have backups available.
Note that by default it replaces emails with a new random e-mail address. To use a fixed email address, just replace the call to `randEmail` with a constant string.